# When can I file for a German Tax Refund?

Tags: taxes, germany, refund

My fiancé and me are planning to get married before the end of this year. I'm Egyptian and he is German. Can we do the tax refund before the end of this year or we hv to wait till next may? Can we do it if we are married in Germany though I have only visit visa not residence? Or we have to wait till the visa change? Does double household apply to him if we renting in Egypt?and also travel expenses as tax refund to visit me in Egypt?(home visiting or it applys only if he is not german)

Comment: Getting married in germany is going to be incredibly difficult.... You're going to have to get some documents with apostils and certified translation.... Other than that it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Thats a lot of questions :). I've answered just the one in the title - if you still need / want answers on the other ones, then you should probably open new questions for them! (I'm afraid I couldn't answer most though..)

Answer (score 2):

Answering the question in your title "Germany tax refund":

Hi, as far as I know, no, you **cannot** submit your tax declaration **before the 1st of January of the following year.**

You don't need to wait for the month May you are referring to - that is simply the regular deadline for submitting your tax declaration - you are always allowed to file it earlier in the year (if you have it ready :P ).

Answer (score 1):

May is not the regular deadline for your tax report.  You have up to 4 years for it but you can  do it until the end of September without further notice. Some people wait as long as possible because you receive good interest from the state.

May should be start of the processing of the tax reports from the current year (even if i had March or April in mind),

As for the question about a double household,  I am not an expert but it is difficult (I doubt that you get it). You need a business reason for having a second household.  Also, you must visit your household distant from work often (twice a month) and the size of the primary must be bigger, etc. I'm not sure if there are limitations for a household outside of Germany.

For marriage, it is probably easier in Egypt if the German authority has an agreement to accept it directly or else I could recommend Denmark for it.

Comment: To add on this: You only have up to 4 years if you are not obliged to file the taxes. If you are obliged due to whatever reasons, you have only time to do it until the end of May.

Comment: End of May used to be the regular deadline for all who *have to* file income tax. This has changed, though and is now end of July (since 2019). In turn, fees for late filing are increased, and AFAIK the tax officers have less leeway in granting prolonged deadlines.